# Flutter + Riverpod - Show loading dialog depending on provider state

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have an application with Flutter and Riverpod, so i created a provider for the AuthController like this

```
final authControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<AuthController, bool>((ref) {
  final authApi = ref.watch(authApiProvider);
  final userApi = ref.watch(userApiProvider);
  final localStorage = ref.watch(localStorageProvider);

  return AuthController(authAPI: authApi, userAPI: userApi, localStorage: localStorage);
});
```

As you can see it's a **StateNotifierProvider**, so inside AuthController sometimes i set **state = false** or **state = true** to say if it's loading or not.

Here's the definition of AuthController

```
class AuthController extends StateNotifier<bool> implements IAuthController { 
      // ....
      void signupWithGoogle(....) {
           state = true;
           // do all the signup stuff
           state = false;
      }
}
```

In the **VIEW**, i can read the value of this state by using:

```
bool isLoading = ref.watch(authControllerProvider);
```

**Problem:**

But the problem is... How do i show a Dialog depending on this value? I tried putting in many places inside the code but all of them break somehow.

Last thing i tried (don't laugh cuz i already tried many things before this) was this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isLoading = ref.watch(authControllerProvider);

    if (isLoading) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        showLoadingAnimation(context);
      });
    } else {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        closeLoadingAnimation(context);
      });
    }
....
```

But with this approach the screen gets all black (without any error)

So what's the correct way of showing and closing a dialog in this case?

Comment: Stop using StateNotifier[Provider].  Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: You are using Riverpod incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want a way to listen to provider state changes and update UI depending on it.

First of all, Use ref.read to call the function responsible for updating the state:

```
ref.read(authControllerProvider.notifier).updateState();
```

then in your build method:

```
ref.listen(authControllerProvider, (previous, next) {
  if(next == true){
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (_){
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
    });
  }else{
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
});
```

In this way, each time state updated the listen function will triggered to give you prev and next state,

what I suggest for you, for loading process, don't show dialog, instead, do it using stack and visibility widget like this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
ref.watch(authControllerProvider);
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        ///your code
        ///
        Visibility(
          visible: ref.watch(authControllerProvider.notifier).state,
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```